# Copy one table row to another using SQL

Tags: pdo, copy, sql-insert

For me, this works:

> INSERT INTO table_A (name, age, city) SELECT name, age, city FROM
>   table_B WHERE id=1

But now I want to set value for the column 'status' in table_A (this values is not present in table_B). Every row must have the 'status=1'. How can I do it? 
I tried to do this, but didn't work:

> INSERT INTO table_A (status, name, age, city) VALUES (1, SELECT name,
>   age, city FROM table_B WHERE id=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 1, name, age, city FROM table_B ...
```

and it has nothing to do with PDO

Comment: Thaaaaaaannk you! It's working now! :))). You're whright it has nothing to do with PDO. Changed the question title.